# group by json array based on combine multiple keys taking too much time

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have below json array I want to group by it based on sourceno and destno combine key.

**Present Code:**

```
let eddarr=[
        {
            "sourceno": "112",
            "destno": "321",
            "edno": "123",
            "eppno": "322"
        },
        {
            "sourceno": "112",
            "destno": "321",
            "edno": "123",
            "eppno": "324"
        },
        {
            "sourceno": "114",
            "destno": "335",
            "edno": "100",
            "eppno": "355"
        },
        {
            "sourceno": "114",
            "destno": "335",
            "edno": "222",
            "eppno": "999"
        }
    ]

    let pobj={}
    let p_data=[]
    let count=0;
    for(key in eddarr) 
    {
    
    let resultarr=eddarr[key]
    let pkey = eddarr[key].sourceno+'-'+eddarr[key].destno;
    let obj = {};
    let isNew = true;
    if(pdata.length > 0){

      for(let j=0;j<pdata.length;j++){

        if(pdata[j].hasOwnProperty(pkey)){
          pdata[j][pkey][pdata[j][pkey].length] = resultarr;
          isNew = false;
          break;
        }
      }
    }

    if(isNew){

      obj[pkey] = new Array();
      obj[pkey][0] = resultarr;
      pdata.push(obj);
    }

console.log(pdata)
```

Above code is working fine and i am getting below result but its running very slow its creating below result for 37K records after 15 min. How can i optimise this code or any other logic need to build. I want to process 1.5  million records but loop is taking too much time.

**Final result** after processing should be like this:

```
[
    {
        "112-321": [
            {
                "edno": "123",
                "eppno": "322"
            },
            {
                "edno": "123",
                "eppno": "324"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "114-335": [
            {
                "edno": "100",
                "eppno": "355"
            },
            {
                "edno": "222",
                "eppno": "999"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Please try to avoid using Indian words here. People living elsewhere aren't going to understand what are "lac records".

Answer (score 1):

You could destructure the object to omit keys and build a single object with grouping keys. From this build an array of objects with a sinlge property.

```js
const
    data = [{ sourceno: "112", destno: "321", edno: "123", eppno: "322" }, { sourceno: "112", destno: "321", edno: "123", eppno: "324" }, { sourceno: "114", destno: "335", edno: "100", eppno: "355" }, { sourceno: "114", destno: "335", edno: "222", eppno: "999" }],
    keys = ['sourceno', 'destno'],
    result = Object
        .entries(data.reduce((r, o) => {
            const key = keys.map(k => {
                let v;
                ({ [k]: v, ...o } = o);
                return v;
            }).join('-');
            (r[key] ??= []).push(o);
            return r;
        }, {}))
        .map(pair => Object.fromEntries([pair]));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: getting SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'  for (r[key] ??= []).push(o);

Comment: replace `r[key] ??= []` with `r[key] = r[key] || []`, a logical or instead of a [logical nullish assignment `??=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment).

Answer (score 0):

```js
    const values = {};
    eddarr = [{ sourceno: "112", destno: "321", edno: "123", eppno: "322" }, { sourceno: "112", destno: "321", edno: "123", eppno: "324" }, { sourceno: "114", destno: "335", edno: "100", eppno: "355" }, { sourceno: "114", destno: "335", edno: "222", eppno: "999" }];
    eddarr.map((entry) => {
        var key = entry.sourceno + '-' + entry.destno;
        if (!values[ key ]) { values[ key ] = []; }
        values[ key ].push({
            edno: entry.edno,
            eppno: entry.eppno
        })
    });
    console.log(Object.keys(values).map(key => { return { [ key ]: values[key] } }));
```

Comment: compare my final result using your code i am getting single object while i have multiple objects in result like your result is {'110005-134003': [ [Object] ],'110005-134003': [ [Object] ],'110005-134003': [ [Object] ]} . I want objects for each record because after this i am processing it in chunks using slice.

Comment: I'm guessing you are using NodeJS, for a full output, use JSON.stringify - or don't use console.log and return [ values ]

Comment: I tried in js.do please check my final result every key pair is in separate { }. hope you understand like [{v1},{v2}...]

Comment: I don't fully understand why you'd want to avoid key/value pairing but there you go. Updated

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT: Although this solution works, there is a faster way of achieving the same result, traversing the input array only once; please make sure to have a look at it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70879983/14201528)]

One way of doing it could be using `Array.prototype.reduce()` (and `Array.prototype.find()`); something like this:

```js
const input = [{
    "sourceno": "112",
    "destno": "321",
    "edno": "123",
    "eppno": "322"
  },
  {
    "sourceno": "112",
    "destno": "321",
    "edno": "123",
    "eppno": "324"
  },
  {
    "sourceno": "114",
    "destno": "335",
    "edno": "100",
    "eppno": "355"
  },
  {
    "sourceno": "114",
    "destno": "335",
    "edno": "222",
    "eppno": "999"
  }
];

const output = input.reduce((acc, item) => {
  const key = `${item.sourceno}-${item.destno}`; // create the object key
  const { edno, eppno } = item; // destructure the attributes to be grouped

  const accItem = acc.find(_item => Object.keys(_item)[0] === key); // check whether there is an element with the same object key

  if (accItem) {
    // in the item is found, update it by adding the attributes to the array
    accItem[key].push({ edno, eppno });
  } else {
    // otherwise create a new item and add it to the accumulator
    acc.push({ [key]: [{ edno, eppno }] });
  }

  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

A faster solution, compared to the one I proposed before, would be using an object to keep track of the items inserted in `pdata`; in this way you can achieve your goal traversing `eddarr` only once.
Please notice in the following code snippet I am using an IIFE to avoid "polluting" the global scope with the `itemsListObj` variable but that is not strictly necessary.

```js
const eddarr = [{
    "sourceno": "112",
    "destno": "321",
    "edno": "123",
    "eppno": "322"
  },
  {
    "sourceno": "112",
    "destno": "321",
    "edno": "123",
    "eppno": "324"
  },
  {
    "sourceno": "114",
    "destno": "335",
    "edno": "100",
    "eppno": "355"
  },
  {
    "sourceno": "114",
    "destno": "335",
    "edno": "222",
    "eppno": "999"
  }
];

const pdata = (function() {
  const itemsListObj = {};

  return eddarr.reduce((acc, { sourceno, destno, edno, eppno }) => {
    const key = `${sourceno}-${destno}`;
    const insertIndex = itemsListObj[key];

    if (insertIndex != null) {
      acc[insertIndex][key].push({ edno, eppno });
    } else {
      acc.push({ [key]: [{ edno, eppno }] });
      itemsListObj[key] = acc.length - 1;
    }

    return acc;
  }, []);
})()


console.log(pdata);
```